# Group by in mongoose gives multiple record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to apply group by aggregation in mongoose by following code

```
app.get('/api/get_conversation_all_carer/:carer_id',function(req,res){
        //Sender = user and receiver = carer
        var data = [];
        var conversation = {status_code:200, data:data};
        Conversation.find({'receiver_id': req.params.carer_id},{sender_id:1},{'group': 'sender_id'},function(err,result)
        {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

which gives me following output

```
[{ _id: 561f985439365e3c2aa9398a,
    sender_id: '55f000a2878075c416ff9879' },
  { _id: 5620cfd0e4b0b1432a7331bb,
    sender_id: '55f000a2878075c416ff9879' }]
```

Here for same sender_id why I am getting two separate record.
I want just sender_id like
[{sender_id: '55f000a2878075c416ff9879'}]

Comment: I usually see `group` as `$group`.  Are you sure `'group'` is correct?

Comment: yes. actually I am not getting any syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) which is a modern version and does better document manipulation in native code without JavaScript execution or translation. I supspect you already found [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in the documentation, but did not realize it is tied to `.aggregate()` and not the `.find()` method:

```
Conversation.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "receiver_id": req.params.carer_id },
        { "$group": { "_id": "$sender_id" } }
    ],
    function(err,result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

Which will return an array of results for the distinct values of the field referenced in the "key" `_id` for `$group`, ( even if only one ) like this:

```
[{_id: '55f000a2878075c416ff9879'}]
```

You can optionally exchange `_id` for `sender_id` using [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), but it's not a good habit to get into, and rather just make your receiving logic accept the "unique key" is always named `_id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [db.collection.group()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/):

```
Conversation.collection.group(
{
    key: {sender_id:1},
    cond: {receiver_id: req.params.carer_id},
    reduce: function ( curr, result ) { },
    initial: { },
    function(err, results){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```